# Windows Auto debugger triggered on TerminateProcess for breakpoint exception

Tags: windows, winapi, process, windbg, visual-studio-debugging

We have an app to collect process dump and its configured in AEDebug reg key to launch on process crash. Some times its triggered for breakpoint exception and dump points to below callstack.

```
0:000> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 0000001d`012df398 00007ffa`65d884f3     ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa
01 0000001d`012df3a0 00007ffa`657734da     ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0xa3
02 0000001d`012df490 00007ffa`5c651cd5     kernel32!ExitProcessImplementation+0xa
03 0000001d`012df4c0 00007ffa`5c652304     mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+0x285
04 0000001d`012df7b0 00007ffa`5bd66398     mscoreei!CLRRuntimeHostInternalImpl::ShutdownAllRuntimesThenExit+0x14
05 0000001d`012df7e0 00007ffa`5bd662e1     clr!EEPolicy::ExitProcessViaShim+0x9c
06 0000001d`012df830 00007ffa`5bcbb936     clr!SafeExitProcess+0x9d
07 0000001d`012dfab0 00007ffa`5bd6a198     clr!HandleExitProcessHelper+0x3e
08 0000001d`012dfae0 00007ffa`657713f2     clr!EEShutDownProcForSTAThread+0x2318
09 0000001d`012dfb10 00007ffa`65d854f4     kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
0a 0000001d`012dfb40 00000000`00000000     ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

~ command in windbg shows this is the only thread in the dump. And there are no managed exceptions.

```
0:000> !pe
There is no current managed exception on this thread

0:000> ~
.  0  Id: 18f4.b07c Suspend: -1 Teb: 00007ff7`24f90000 Unfrozen
```

Why is the debugger triggered for this callstack? Anyone else seen the same?

Update:

```
0:000> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

0:000> !avrf
Application verifier is not enabled for this process.
Use appverif.exe tool to enable it.

0:000> !gflag
Current NtGlobalFlag contents: 0x00000000

0:000> !gle
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0x6 (6) - The handle is invalid.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000008 - An invalid HANDLE was specified.
```

Comment: @ThomasWeller, i have updated question with outputs of these 3 commands. but !gle output shows some error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. `!gle` results can be quite old and not match the problem you see.

Comment: @devstability can you try a standard debugger instead of your app to capture the dump? Like procdump or windbg?